# NSIS not displaying new control after change ui

Tags: nsis

I took ui.cpp and default.rc from the svn, compiled it, used changeui ---> works!

I can't display new controls. This is a section from the new default.rc

```
IDD_LICENSE DIALOGEX 0, 0, 266, 130 STYLE DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CONTROL | WS_CHILD
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    ICON            IDR_MAINFRAME,IDR_MAINFRAME,0,0,22,20
    LTEXT           "pppppppppppppppppppppp",507,25,0,241,23
    LTEXT           "email user",508, 172, 106, 233, 31
    CONTROL         "",IDC_EDIT1,RICHEDIT_CLASS,WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL | 
                WS_TABSTOP | 0x804,0,24,266,105
END
```

In the nsh script, on create function of a page I tried:

```
GetDlgItem $MyHandle $HWNDPARENT507
MessageBox MB_OK $MyHandle //this is always 0 no matter what I tried in the previous line!!!
EnableWindow $MyHandle 1
```

I also tried editing the original defalt.exe with resource hacker but nsis wouldn't display new text/control.

How can I display the new text and control???

Answer (score 1):

The NSIS GUI is actually one dialog window with another dialog window inside it.

[image: NSIS inner and outer dialog]

You first need to find the inner dialog before you can find the controls in it:

```
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT    ; Find the inner dialog (See attached picture)
GetDlgItem $MyHandle $0 507              ; Find the control
```

Complete example:

```
!define ResHacker "$%localappdata%\Programs\ResHacker.exe" ; TODO: Adjust this path
!define myui "${__FILE__}\..\mytempui.exe"

!tempfile res
!tempfile rc
!delfile "${rc}"
!delfile "${res}"
!define /redef rc "${res}.rc"
!define /redef res "${res}.res"
!appendfile "${rc}" '#define IDD_LICENSE                     102$\r$\n'
!appendfile "${rc}" '#define IDC_EDIT1                       1000$\r$\n'
!appendfile "${rc}" '#define RICHEDIT_CLASS "RichEdit20W"$\r$\n'
!appendfile "${rc}" 'LANGUAGE 0x09, 0x01$\r$\n'
!appendfile "${rc}" 'IDD_LICENSE DIALOGEX 0, 0, 266, 130$\r$\n STYLE DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CONTROL | WS_CHILD$\r$\n'
!appendfile "${rc}" 'FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1$\r$\n'
!appendfile "${rc}" 'BEGIN$\r$\n'
!appendfile "${rc}" '    LTEXT           "pppppppppppppppppppppp",507,25,0,241,23,SS_LEFT|WS_VISIBLE$\r$\n'
!appendfile "${rc}" '    LTEXT           "email user",508, 172, 106, 233, 31,SS_LEFT|WS_VISIBLE$\r$\n'
!appendfile "${rc}" '    CONTROL         "",IDC_EDIT1,RICHEDIT_CLASS,WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE | 0x804,0,24,266,55$\r$\n'
!appendfile "${rc}" 'END$\r$\n'
!system '"${ResHacker}" -open "${rc}" -save "${res}" -action compile -log CON' = 0
!delfile "${rc}"
!system '"${ResHacker}" -open "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\UIs\default.exe" -save "${myui}" -action addoverwrite -res "${res}" -mask DIALOG,102,1033 -log CON' = 0
!delfile "${res}"

ChangeUI IDD_LICENSE "${myui}"
Page License "" MyLicShow
Page InstFiles

!include WinMessages.nsh
Var MyHandle
Function MyLicShow
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT    ; Find the inner dialog (See attached picture)
GetDlgItem $MyHandle $0 507              ; Find the control
SendMessage $MyHandle ${WM_SETTEXT} "" "STR:New control text"
SetCtlColors $MyHandle ff0000 transparent
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: @Andres thanks. I added   MessageBox MB_OK $MyHandle and it always show 0. Am I at the wrong window?

Comment: It is impossible to diagnose your issue like this, I added a complete example

Comment: That's true. I'll try to built a minimal example.