# How do I center the UI and stretch the shape over the entire resolution? NSIS

Tags: user-interface, installation, size, nsis

I put the MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS form.
Next, for the installer, I set the resolution to 1280 by 720.

```
!define WIDTH 1280
!define HEIGHT 720

Function .onGUIInit
    GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1000 
    System::Call 'user32::MoveWindow(i $HWNDPARENT, i 0, i 0, i ${WIDTH}, i ${HEIGHT}, i 1)' MoveWindow(i $0, i 0, i 0, i ${WIDTH}, i ${HEIGHT}, i 1)' 
FunctionEnd
```

But all the UI elements are located in the upper-left corner.
Is it possible to center and stretch the form (UI elements) to the entire size of the window?
If not, how do I stretch the component box and description box?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TCVp.png)

I searched , but I never found an easy solution. Is it really impossible to manipulate elements of ready-made forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sane way to change the UI is to use [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to modify one of the files in `...\NSIS\Contrib\UIs` and apply it with `!define MUI_UI myfile.exe`.

If you want to move things at run-time you can call `MoveWindow` or `SetWindowPos` (SetWindowPos allows you to move without resizing a control). If you do this, remember that some controls are in [the inner dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5832395#https://stackoverflow.com/a/69155245) and some are not.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, and you actually posted a correct solution: *A*ll you need is to move/resize the controls individually.**

For example a Next button:

```
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1 ; Get the handle to button
System::Call 'user32::MoveWindow(i $HWNDPARENT, i <param> , i <param> , i <param> i <param>  i 1)' MoveWindow(i $0, i <param> , i <param> , i <param> , i <param>, i 1)'
```

There is way how to move all controls in a bulk (Windows API does not support that) so iterate over all controls you want to move/resize, get their handles (see NSIS docs) and call the MoveWindow Win API function with appropriate parameters:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow